# Is there any harm if i use the sharepoint farm account (managed account) to create site collections,lists, columns

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, administration, service-account, sharepoint-farm

we have configured a new sharepoint 2013 on-premise farm.and i used the sharepoint farm account as the service account inside the configuration wizards.

Now i want to start creating site collections, lists, site columns, etc.
so is there any harm if i use the sharepoint farm account (which is a managed account) to create site collections, lists, site columns, etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the site collection, you have two options either create via powershell or Central admin.

- for that you need a account which is part of farm admin group on the central admin, use that account login to the central admin and create a site collection(s)
- Now when you create a site collection during that process it will ask
  you the Primary and Secondary Site collection admin. You can give any
  user account.
- Once site collection created successfully, you login on that site with
  the account you mentioned during its creation. Now you can create
  lists and libraries under that site collection.

So this is the process, Now the question is, can i use farm admin as Site collection admin. Short Answer **Yes**. You can use any domain account for this.

But as a Best Practice, it is highly recommended dont use that account as it is running SharePoint critical process i.e Central admin, SharePoint timer service etc. if for some reason use lock the account, SharePoint will be go down.

Comment: i did not get your point when you say "_if for some reason use lock the account, SharePoint will be go down._" ??

Comment: ok, if you are using the same account for everything (in this case farm account), now your forget the password or misstype the password, which will lock the account. if account get locked then SharePoint will go down. this is one example

Comment: so you mean it is better not to create lists, site column using managed account, while it is better to do so using the site collection admin ?

Comment: You are mixing two things....you cant create a site collection in SharePoint farm without an account which is part of Farm admin group on Central admin. But you dont need this account to create the list, column etc. when you create a site collection make your own account as primary site collection admin....once site will created then you can browse that site with your user account and create all the list, columns etc.

Comment: i am not mixing things this is what meant, to create the site collection using central admin i need a user who is inside the farm admin group. then i can set the site collection admin to be for example myself, and then create the list, site column, etc using the site collection admin??

Comment: I am not offending you, dont take me wrong....I am just trying to explain you....You can create the site collection from Central admin but List, libraries or site columns those are site collection scoped item not the farm scope. So for that you have to login with the Site collection admin to create the stuff under your site collection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48604/discussion-between-waqas-sarwar-mcse-and-john-g).